# Why is there 0 nodes in my link list? When I printf count in the getCount function, it writes 0, but there should be 3 Nodes read from file

Tags: c, count, linked-list

It looks like function load doesnt insert anything. If I want to know the size of link list in the funtion getCount, it returns me number 0, but there are 3 lines of data in the file I read from

```
typedef struct employees{ 
  char first_name[30];
  char second_name[30];
  long long int ID;
  float salary;
  struct zamestnanci* next;
} EMPLOYEES;

void load(FILE *f, EMPLOYEES** head){

  int i;

  if((f = fopen("zamestnanci.txt", "r")) == NULL)   
  { 
        printf("Zaznamy neboli nacitane\n");
        exit(0);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)    {
    EMPLOYEES* temp1 = (EMPLOYEES*) malloc (sizeof(EMPLOYEES));
    while(fscanf(f, "%s %s %lld %f", &temp1->first_name, &temp1->second_name, &(temp1->ID), &temp1->salary) == 4)
    {

        temp1->next=NULL;
        if(head == NULL){
            temp1->next= head;
            head=temp1; 
        }       

        EMPLOYEES* temp2 = head;
        while(temp2->next!= NULL)
        {
            temp2->next= temp1;
        }
    }
```

This is function getCount, which return count = 0, but there are 3 lines in the file:

```
int getCount(EMPLOYEES** head)  
{  
  int count = 0; // Initialize count  
  ZAMESTNANCI* current = head; // Initialize current  
  while (current != NULL)  
  {  
    count++;  
    current = current->dalsi;  
  }  
  printf("Count %d\n", count);
  return count;  
}
```

This is main:

```
 int main()
 {
   FILE *f;
   struct EMPLOYEES*head;

   head = NULL;

   load(f, &head);
   getCount(head);

}
```

Comment: Try rewording the question a bit, add some more text then put that code chunk a bit nicer in a code block - its a bit hard to read and to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your `int getCount(ZAMESTNANCI** head)` should be `int getCount(ZAMESTNANCI* head)`, just one pointer. If you compile with warnings enabled (and you should) it will complain about that.

Comment: It didn't help. I think that the function load is not working as it should

Comment: @Hihaha  look at my answer, you have several errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> ```
> typedef struct employees{ 
>   char first_name[30];
>   char second_name[30];
>   long long int ID;
>   float salary;
>   struct zamestnanci* next;
> } EMPLOYEES;
> ```

I suppose `struct zamestnanci* next;` is `struct employees* next;`

In

> ```
>  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)    {
>    EMPLOYEES* temp1 = (EMPLOYEES*) malloc (sizeof(EMPLOYEES));
>    while(fscanf(f, "%s %s %lld %f", &temp1->first_name, &temp1->second_name, &(temp1->ID), &temp1->salary) == 4)
>    {
>       ...
>    }
> ```

in the *scanf* `&temp1->first_name, &temp1->second_name,` must be `temp1->first_name, temp1->second_name,`

all is read into the *while* at the first turn of the *for* and all the time using the same unique allocated EMPLOYEES

probably you wanted a *if* rather than a *while* and adding an *else* to go out of the *for* after you free *temp1*

In

> ```
>    temp1->next=NULL;
>    if(head == NULL){
>        temp1->next= head;
>        head=temp1; 
>    }
> ```

`head == NULL` is impossible, you wanted to check `*head == NULL` (note even *head* is not a pointer to a pointer `temp1->next= head;` is useless because you do again `temp1->next=NULL;`)

In

> ```
>    EMPLOYEES* temp2 = head;
>    while(temp2->next!= NULL)
>    {
>        temp2->next= temp1;
>    }
> ```

you do not modify the value of the variable *temp2*, fortunately because you construct wrongly the list `head->next` is always NULL and  you do not loop forever

Probably you wanted to add the new cell at the end of the list so you need to replace

> ```
>    temp1->next=NULL;
>    if(head == NULL){
>        temp1->next= head;
>        head=temp1; 
>    }       
>
>    EMPLOYEES* temp2 = head;
>    while(temp2->next!= NULL)
>    {
>        temp2->next= temp1;
>    }
> ```

By

```
  temp1->next=NULL;
  if (*head != NULL) {
    EMPLOYEES** temp2 = &(*head)->next;

    while (*temp2 != NULL)
      temp2 = &(*temp2)->next;

    *temp2 = temp1;
  }
  else
    *head = temp1;
```

As said in a remark `int getCount(EMPLOYEES** head)` must be `int getCount(EMPLOYEES* head)`

Also in that function `current = current->dalsi;` must be `current = current->next;` and `ZAMESTNANCI* current = head;` must be `EMPLOYEES* current = head;`

Note in

> ```
> fscanf(f, "%s %s %lld %f", &temp1->first_name, &temp1->second_name, &(temp1->ID), &temp1->salary) == 4)
> ```

there is also no protection against an overflow of `first_name` and `second_name` in case at least one of them have more than 29 characters, and you can go out of the allocated block with an undefined behavior

In *main*

> ```
>  struct EMPLOYEES*head;
> ```

must be

```
EMPLOYEES*head;
```

It is useless to have *f* in *main* and to give it in argument because it is not set in *main*

---

Doing all the changes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct employees{ 
  char first_name[30];
  char second_name[30];
  long long int ID;
  float salary;
  struct employees* next;
} EMPLOYEES;

void load(EMPLOYEES** head){
  FILE *f;
  int i;

  if((f = fopen("zamestnanci.txt", "r")) == NULL)   
  { 
        printf("Zaznamy neboli nacitane\n");
        exit(0);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)    {
    EMPLOYEES* temp1 = (EMPLOYEES*) malloc (sizeof(EMPLOYEES));
    if(fscanf(f, "%29s %29s %lld %f", temp1->first_name, temp1->second_name, &(temp1->ID), &temp1->salary) == 4)
    {
      temp1->next=NULL;
      if (*head != NULL) {
        EMPLOYEES** temp2 = &(*head)->next;

        while (*temp2 != NULL)
          temp2 = &(*temp2)->next;

        *temp2 = temp1;
      }
      else
        *head = temp1;
    }
    else {
      free(temp1);
      break;
    }
  }
}

int getCount(EMPLOYEES* head)  
{  
  int count = 0; // Initialize count  
  EMPLOYEES* current = head; // Initialize current  
  while (current != NULL)  
  {  
    printf("%s %s %lld %f\n", current->first_name, current->second_name, current->ID, current->salary);
    count++;  
    current = current->next;  
  }  
  printf("Count %d\n", count);
  return count;  
}  

int main()
 {
   EMPLOYEES * head = NULL;

   load(&head);
   getCount(head);

   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat zamestnanci.txt 
js back 1 2
lv beethoven 3 4
wa mozart 5 6
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
js back 1 2.000000
lv beethoven 3 4.000000
wa mozart 5 6.000000
Count 3
```

Comment: yes, I want to insert new Nodes at the end of the list

Comment: about first name and second name we don't have to worry, it is fine

Comment: @Hihaha up to a change in the file or the code, to suppose an input always correspond to the hope rather than to check its validity is a source of a lot of problems ...

Comment: It is just school project and we have to set the lenght of this names to 30 characters, so it is ok

Comment: @Hihaha frankly there are so many errors in your code, it is not possible to compile it for so many reasons. Next time check the code at least compile before to give it

Comment: @Hihaha I finished to enter my answer whose includes an execution showing it works

Comment: great! thank you so much! now it worked also for me!

Comment: by the green pipe ?

Comment: @Hihaha yes you did